# Contacts in a calendar appointment

Tags: icloud, calendar

I've noticed that I can add contacts to a calendar appointment. What is this useful for? Will they be notified of the appointment? What can they do with the appointment? What is the whole purpose? I can invite contacts to attend, so I don't see what this is used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding contacts will send automatic email invitations. The contacts can accept the invitation and the appointment will appear in their own calendar(s).

Comment: No, that is not what is happening. Contacts that I add to an appointment are shown in the *Notes*, in my case the email address. No email is sent though, unless I select *Email all* or add them to *Invitees*.

Comment: @DanielLidström - How do you add contacts other than "Add Invitee.."? I must have misunderstood the question. The only reasonable reason (sic) to add contacts to your Notes would be so you have their info available on each device you sync the calendar with (in case you don't also sync the contacts).

Comment: Sorry, my question does not really make any sense. I see that now. You see, I'm using another app to manage my calendars (Week Cal) and it seems it is this app that allows me to add contacts in this way. Sorry for the noise!